# How do I delete/remove dynamic links in firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

Where is the delete/remove button to remove dynamic links/deep links within a Firebase project?

[image: remove dynamic links in Firebase]

Comment: I need the same. Did you guys figure out how to delete dynamic links?

Comment: There is no option for removing created links.
this is very BAD. I'm also looking for this but not found any solution.
This is the big issue for us to create test link in live account.

Comment: Feature to being able to "archive" the link is being worked on. Except that old links garbaging your Firebase console, what problem this causing for you?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

Comment: we can remove dynamic links and dynamic link domain in latest firebase console.

Answer (score 11):

It's not currently possible to remove existing links without removing the entire project. Just remove the link placement instead and create a new link if necessary.

Comment: This doesn't work if the link is placed in an email or sent in almost any manner

Answer (score 5):

**Update December 11th, 2017:** You can now do this! From the Firebase console, select the little three dots next to your link and then choose the "Archive Link" option from the pop-up menu. This will essentially delete it for all intents and purposes. (The deleted link will still work, but it'll no longer show up in the Firebase console.)

[image: Archived link]

Comment: but if I want to create a link with the same name, will I be able to?

Comment: Daniel, you would just edit the existing link instead.

Comment: I mean after I archived

Comment: @ToddKerpelman thanks, but what about if you don't want the link to be used anymore? Like a one-time use. In my case, I'm using it for sign-up and I'd like to be able to block it from use again. Of course, there are other places in my app where I can put this logic, but it's still a good feature. I think this is more useful than "removing my copy of this link" aka, archiving it. So this is just "hide" instead of delete.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Archive Link" option to delete it, It's the only way to do it.
The real problem is that you can not delete THE DYNAMIC LINKS DOMAIN itself as the time of writing this post.