# Dynamic Links domain not available

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

According to the docs, there should be a Dynamic Links domain for my project, which is displayed at the top of the Dynamic Links page. The docs have a screen capture like so:

[Location of domain according to the Firebase documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7P2Xd.png)

However, on the Dynamic Links page for my project there is no such domain, at least not one I can see. Here is a screen shot (I've blacked out identifying info, there was no domain under the black square or circle!):

[Screen shot of Dynamic Links page with no domain displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/567by.png)

I've tried looking through settings and options in case there was some kind of toggle, but haven't found anything relevant.

Comment: Looks like recent regression, domain should be shown even if you did not created any links yet. Created internal bug to fix this. Answer below is a good workaround meanwhile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a test link with whatever informations you want and you will have a complete link with your app domain like: app_code.app.goo.gl

Comment: Thanks, I see in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37486585/how-do-i-delete-remove-dynamic-links-in-firebase?rq=1) that you cannot delete or remove dynamic links from your project.

Might use your solution as a workaround if there is no other, but I'd prefer to not 'junk up' my project if it can be avoided.

I tested it on another project but get a non-specific error message. Perhaps there is something wrong with my projects fundamentally.

Comment: I managed to create a link after another attempt and the domain link is now displayed on the page as stated in the docs. I guess this will do for now, so I'll accept yours as the answer. I've sent a bug report to firebase, at the very least the docs can be updated with the workaround (though I assume this is a bug).

Comment: @Pete is your link working correctly ?
I created one but not working correctly :(

Comment: Not been able to try it out just yet! Working through all this as a first timer so I wouldn't be then best source to rely on.