# Firebase Dynamic Link domain not being created as expected

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm trying to set up my dynamic link domain to use in Facebook Login with Firebase, and according to the docs, as stated in this question: [Dynamic Links domain not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47593124/dynamic-links-domain-not-available), it says that the domain should look like `app_code.app.goo.gl`.

However, when I follow the steps to do so, the domain always comes as `https://custom_link.page.link` and it doesn't work in the cordova build

(After placing the dynamic link domain, the build always returns this error: `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: Cannot read property 'manifest' of undefined` and if I remove the link, it works again)

I don't know if it's related, but all of the tutorials and guides that I've checked always use the dynamic link domain as `app_code.app.goo.gl`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the confusion - we just launched the page.link domain, so some of the documentation is still catching up. Everything else should look the same after that, so the main thing is to make sure that your app is set up to handle the domain you have for your links - in this case the page.link one.