# Delete created dynamic link from firebase and create new custom URL using firebase console

Tags: firebase, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links, custom-url

I have created dynamic link under firebase with firebase provided domain, but now I need to replace that dynamic link url with my custom url.
And does dynamic link supports the custom url Or domain?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37486585/how-do-i-delete-remove-dynamic-links-in-firebase) help?

Comment: By archiving link does domain also get archived? And can we create another domain? That's what I am not sure about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dynamic link can't be deleted, archive link is one alternative.
To create custom domain

1. Click on drop down of existing domain and select add URL prefix.
2. Popup will open inside the you have to follow 4 steps
   A. Add your domain name.
   B. Click on continue, configure it and press continue.
   C. Verify domain with TXT and paste provide value in it press
   continue.
   D. Add generated records with there ip and click on finish.
   3.Check for DNS server activation inside hosting tab in Firebase and verify it with provided link.
   Sometimes it takes time to get DNS up