# How long is the lifespan of a Firebase Dynamic Link created via API?

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I have successfully created a dynamic link via Firebase using their API as listed here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/rest#creating-a-short-dynamic-link. I was wondering what the lifespan of one these "generated-on-the-fly" dynamic links were?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamic Links have no time-to-live, and don't expire.

You *can* [archive a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37486585/how-do-i-delete-remove-dynamic-links-in-firebase) from the Firebase console, but that merely hides it and doesn't expire the existing link.

This reads like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) though. Since dynamic links carry no authentication/authorization information, they are valid indefinitely. If any authentication is required to see the contents that the link target, you'd implement that in your app after requiring the user to authentication/authorize after the link is resolved.

If the link target has become invalid in your app, you'll want to set up a redirect in your app - so that users who have the old link end up in a useful location too. This is essentially the same that you'd do with links on a web site: instead of letting the web server show a 404 page, it's better to set up redirects to the new location of the relevant content.